# Bind to my class with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, class, binding, dependency-properties, code-behind

I am sorry if this question is double somewhere, I've searched but did not find.

I have created my own class.

```
    Public Class MyListService
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal Title As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Title))
        End Sub

        Private _IsLoggedIn As Boolean = False
    Public Property IsLoggedIn As Boolean
        Get
            Return _IsLoggedIn
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If _IsLoggedIn <> value Then
                _IsLoggedIn = value
                Call OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

In WPF project, I have in codebehind

```
Private WithEvents cWebService As new MyListService
```

In XAML:

> `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" x:Name="chkIsLoggedIn" />`

Please can you tell me how to bind that "IsLoggedIn" property now to the Checkbox?

Regards

Comment: You should probably read up on [the basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#creating_a_binding)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have absolutely no VB experience but I've used WPF with C#.

Here is my **guess**:
you need to set `DataContext` of your `CheckBox` to point to the `MyListService` instance for the binding to work since the binding systems needs to know which object the `IsLoggedIn` property belongs to.